# Import a module in a dynamically created module (node, browsers)

Tags: javascript

I am successfully importing a dynamically created module using this construct:

```
const binString = Array.from(new TextEncoder().encode(moduleText), (byte) => String.fromCodePoint(byte)).join("");
const url = 'data:text/javascript;base64,' + btoa(binString);
var mod2 = await import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ url);
```

Works both in Node and in Chrome.

However, if I import some static module in that dynamic module, node says:

```
node:internal/errors:496
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:778:13)
    at getPackageScopeConfig (node:internal/modules/esm/package_config:14:24)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:736:25)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:831:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1036:11)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:251:12)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:140:32)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:33)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  input: './package.json',
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'
}
```

How it can be fixed?